# Dplyr Pipe Forecast next 5 items by Group

Tags: r, dplyr, forecast

I am trying to forecast by each group within a data frame (in this case LSOA), for the next 5 years. I have a data set of three columns: `LSOA`, `Date` and `Value`. Similar to this:

| LSOA | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E01026449 | 31/03/2021 | 401 |
| E01026449 | 31/03/2022 | 415 |
| E01026449 | 31/03/2023 | 441 |
| E01026450 | 31/03/2021 | 413 |
| E01026450 | 31/03/2022 | 428 |
| E01026450 | 31/03/2023 | 440 |
| E01026451 | 31/03/2021 | 607 |
| E01026451 | 31/03/2022 | 625 |
| E01026451 | 31/03/2023 | 633 |

I have tried several nested lists solutions, none of which are working as it is just fitting the existing year values and I am not sure where to put the `predict` and `h=` to get the next x results.

My completely broken code below:

```
datamodel<-split(data[, -1], data$LSOA)

ld <- lapply(datamodel, function(x) {ts(c(t(x[,-2])),start = c(2010,3,31), frequency = 1)})
lest<-lapply(ld, function(x){holt(x)})

lts<- lapply(lest, function(x){predict(x, newdata=1)})

lts <- lapply(ld, holt, model = "nZZ")
```

I know I need to:

1.) Group by LSOA 
2.) Develop a model for each group 
3.) Apply model to prediction for the group

So ideally I would be able to predict and append the `31/03/2024` number for each `LSOA` or set `h` to some number of future predictions. But I am missing something silly here.

How can I achieve this all in a dplyr pipe?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are 32k LSOAs in England. I assume you're not going for interpretability here as you're going to end up with 32k models with their own parameters - which may also be slow to estimate. What's the advantage of this over a mixed model with random effects for each LSOA? Or if you just want the predictions, why use regression over a machine learning model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the map() function from purrr on the levels of LSOA.It creates a list with your sub data.tables. Then, using map again, you can throw any prediction on each one of your data.table, returning a list of your models.

```
library(tidyverse)

data=tribble(~LSOA,~Date,~Value,
             "E01026449","31/03/2021",401,
             "E01026449",   "31/03/2022",   415,
             "E01026449" ,  "31/03/2023" ,  441,
             "E01026450"    ,"31/03/2021 "  ,413,
             "E01026450",   "31/03/2022",   428,
             "E01026450" ," 31/03/2023" ,   440,
             "E01026451"    ,"31/03/2021"   ,607,
             "E01026451",   "31/03/2022",   625,
             "E01026451" ,  "31/03/2023" ,  633,)

levels (as.factor(data$LSOA)) %>% 
  map(~{return(data %>% filter(LSOA==.x))}) %>%
  map(~{#Insert prediction here
#For example 
lm(Value~Date, data=.x)
# Will not work beacause of the formats
                 })
```

I didn't get what you wanted to predict, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri, I want to the predict the next `n` number of `Values` in the series for LSOA. So for LSOA `E01026451` on the date `31/03/2024` the value will be something like `640` (given the previous values form the same LSOA are 607,625,633).

Comment: The simpler way would be to change the format of your date, to have the number of days from the first date you have (for example, if your first date is 31/01/2019, the date 1/02/2019 would be 1, 03/02/2019 would be 3 and so on and so forth). I think this is possible with the lubridate package, but I don't exactly know how.

Comment: Then you could visualize the shape of your data, doing a simple date~values graph. That helps to see the relationship betwenn your two variables. You can then choose to do a simple linear regression or a polynomial one (eg. values = B1*dates + B2*dates² + ...) according to the relashionship between the two.